# Where can I see my purchase history?

Tags: xbox-network

I have many games that I've redeemed on the xbox live marketplace (thanks in large part to the [Games with Gold program](http://www.xbox.com/live/games-with-gold)), but I have not downloaded these items so they are not in my "download history" or "my games" on my console. I want to keep track of the content I have access to, but **I cannot find a list of items that I have redeemed/purchased.** My purchase history on the [xbox transaction history page](https://account.xbox.com/) is blank as is that for my [Microsoft transaction history](https://commerce.microsoft.com/PaymentHub/Transaction) aside from gold membership renewal and some points to currency conversion. I know that I have successfully redeemed items because viewing the pages of some redeemed items gives me the option to download to my console and states a purchased date.

Playstation Store provides a [full history](https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/liquid/cam/media/media-list.action) of all digital item transactions. Most digital items redeemed through Nintendo are at least added to [the registered product list](https://club.nintendo.com/account.do). **Does Microsoft provide any equivalent form of purchase history and how do I get there?**

I am aware that I could go through every games with gold released and check my ownership one-by-one, but that does not include items purchased or redeemed outside of that program. I could go through every item ever released on Xbox 360 or Xbox One individually to compile a complete list myself, but that seems to be an immense waste of time when I clearly don't own a large percentage of those items and such a list should conceivably already exist in the form of a purchase history.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that this can only be done on the consoles.

For Xbox 360: Sign in, go to **Settings** and select **Account**. Select **Download History** and then you'll see all of the content that you purchased. http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/downloadable-content/redownload-content

For Xbox One: From the **Home** screen, select **My Games and Apps**. Then scroll to the right and you'll see **Ready to Install** which will list all of your games. If there is a controller icon on that game, that means that you have DLC for it, which you can access by pressing the menu button and selecting **Manage Game**. http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/downloadable-content/locate-downloaded-content

Comment: They were in my Download History after all. I was looking at the wrong screen. What a misleading heading under which to place things that have never been downloaded. Only being through the console means that I cannot view my Xbox One Games until I actually get the console. Excellent information. Hopefully Microsoft makes this information more accessible in the future. Maybe the unofficial API has an endpoint I can leverage for easier copy/pasting.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you are looking for;
[Xbox 360 Purchase History](https://live.xbox.com/en-AU/Download/History). Note I got this link after signing into my Australian Xbox Live account and contains `en-AU` in the link. You may want to try and change it to your region/locale if it doesn't automatically do so for you.

Comment: It redirects automatically to the corresponding locale if you were logged in before clicking the link